# Custom collection does not work in Template10, but does work in blank project

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

As the title suggests, I try to port a simple app to template 10 and throws me the following error:

Cannot determine the item type of collection type'Garage.Collections.GroupedObservableCollection`2[System.String, Garage.Models.Car]' because it has more than one Add method or ICollection implementation. To make this collection type usable in XAML, add a public Add(object) method, implement System.Collections.IList or a single System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Since this works outside of template10 I am kind of stumped why this occurs.
The Nuget Packages have the same versions, so only the template10 packages are different from the working version. Target platforms are the same.

The collection class I use is [GroupedObservableCollection](https://github.com/mikegoatly/GroupedObservableCollection/tree/master/Munklesoft.Common.Collections)

It is used as a collectionviewsource in XAML.

[Here is an overview of the classes and methods in VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9vco.jpg)

Thanks for having a look!

I fail to see what the problem is and why Template10 says no.

Comment: Suggestion : Consider using Windows Template Studio to generate your projects, it is very dynamic and customizeable, also most active in the uwp community.

Comment: How did you use the `GroupedObservableCollection` in your Template10 project? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: As I stated above, I fed it into a CollectionViewSource defined in my View's Resources . The GroupedObservableCollection is instanciated in the viewmodel and is populated by a query on a "master" collection. 
Nothing exotic going on. 
It is complaining about the class itself, so it is most likely not related in the implementation but rather something with package and target versions. 

I took touseefbsb's advice and turned to WTS.
No issues whatsoever there.